# Why won't the numbers stay random?

Tags: c++, random, numbers, srand

I have been coding a blackjack game that is almost done it's first stage of development.  I am almost done, the only problem is that the random numbers that are generated in this part:

```
if(x.hit == 1) {

            if (x.userShowCardThree == 0) {
                x.userShowCardThree = 1 + (rand()%11);
                int dealerHit1 = x.userShowCardThree;
                x.userTotal += dealerHit1;
                x.cardCount++;

            }
            else {
                if (x.userShowCardFour == 0) {
                    x.userShowCardFour = 1 + (rand()%11);
                    int dealerHit2 = x.userShowCardFour;
                    x.userTotal += dealerHit2;
                    x.cardCount++;

                }
                else {
                    if (x.userShowCardFive ==0) {
                        x.userShowCardFive = 1 + (rand()%11);
                        int dealerHit3 = x.userShowCardFive;
                        x.userTotal += dealerHit3;
                        x.cardCount++;

                    }
                }
            }
```

is not the same as the numbers generated in the final part:

```
        cout << "You had a total of: " << x.userTotal << endl;
```

as i keep getting different numbers.  I will paste my entire code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

void setRand() {
srand(time(0));

}
class Game {
 public:

int userCards[11] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
int dealerCards[11] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
int userShowCardOne = userCards[1 + (rand()%11)];
int userShowCardTwo = userCards[1 + (rand()%11)];
int dealerShowCard = dealerCards[1 + (rand()%11)];
int dealerHiddenCard = dealerCards[1 + (rand()%11)];
int userShowCards[5] = {userShowCardOne, userShowCardTwo, userShowCardThree,       userShowCardFour, userShowCardFive};
int userShowCardThree = 0;
int userShowCardFour = 0;
int userShowCardFive = 0;
int fresh = 1;
int beginningInput;
int hit = 1;
int dealerTotal = dealerShowCard + dealerHiddenCard;
int userTotal = userShowCardOne + userShowCardTwo;
int cardCount = 2;
int runGame = 1;
private:

};


// int a = 1 + rand()%11;
/*int b = 1 + rand()%11;
int c = 1 + rand()%11;
int d = 1 + rand()%11;
int e = 1 + rand()%11;
int f = 1 + rand()%11;
int g = 1 + rand()%11;
int h = 1 + rand()%11;
*/






int startGame();
int main() {
srand(time(0));
Game x;
cout << "Welcome to BlackJack 1.0.0" << endl;
cout << "Press: " <<endl;
cout << "1 ----- New Game" << endl;
cout << "2 ----- Help" << endl;
cin >> x.beginningInput;

if(x.beginningInput == 1){
    startGame();
    cout << "The dealer had: " << endl;
    cout << x.dealerHiddenCard << endl;
    cout << x.dealerShowCard << endl;
    while(x.dealerTotal <= 16) {
        cout << "The dealer has decided to hit" << endl;
        int dealerHit = 1 + (rand()%11);
        cout << "The dealer has gotten " << dealerHit << endl;
        x.dealerTotal += dealerHit;
    }
    cout << "The dealer has decided to stay" << endl;

    cout << "The dealer had a total of " << x.dealerTotal << endl;

    cout << "You had a total of: " << x.userTotal << endl;

    if (x.dealerTotal > 21 && x.userTotal <= 21) {
        cout << "The dealer busted. You won!" << endl;
    }
    else if (x.userTotal > 21 && x.dealerTotal <= 21) {
        cout << "You busted.  The Dealer Won" << endl;
    }
    else if (x.userTotal > 21 && x.dealerTotal > 21) {
        cout << "You and the dealer both busted. Tie" << endl;
    }
    else {

        if (x.dealerTotal > x.userTotal) {
            cout << "Sorry, you lost to the dealer" << endl;

        }
    else if (x.dealerTotal < x.userTotal) {
        cout << "Congrats, you won!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You and the dealer tied. " << endl;
    }
    }

    cout << "Would you like to play again? 1 to play again, 0 to quit" << endl;
    cin  >> x.beginningInput;
    if (x.beginningInput == 1){
        startGame();
    }
    else if (x.beginningInput == 0){
        return 0;
    }
}
else if (x.beginningInput == 0) {
    cout << "Thanks for playing!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Here's the help section" << endl;
}

}

int startGame() {
Game x;
srand(time(0));
if (x.fresh != 1){
    cout << "NEW GAME\n \n "  << endl;

}

while (x.runGame == 1) {
        cout <<  "Dealer: \n" << endl;
        cout << "X" << endl;
        cout << x.dealerShowCard << endl;
        cout << "You: \n" << endl;

        cout << x.userShowCardOne << endl;
        cout << x.userShowCardTwo << endl;
        x.userTotal = x.userShowCardOne + x.userShowCardTwo;
        if (x.userShowCardThree != 0) {
            cout << x.userShowCardThree << endl;
        }
        if (x.userShowCardFour != 0) {
            cout << x.userShowCardFour << endl;
            cout << "You can only hit one more time!" << endl;
        }
        if (x.userShowCardFive != 0) {
            cout << x.userShowCardFive << endl;
        }
    if(x.cardCount > 5) {
        cout << "sorry, there is a 5 card limit.";
    }
        cout << "Would you like to hit or stay? (1 for hit or 2 for stay)" << endl;
        cin >> x.hit;
        x.fresh = 2;

        if(x.hit == 1) {

            if (x.userShowCardThree == 0) {
                x.userShowCardThree = 1 + (rand()%11);
                int dealerHit1 = x.userShowCardThree;
                x.userTotal += dealerHit1;
                x.cardCount++;

            }
            else {
                if (x.userShowCardFour == 0) {
                    x.userShowCardFour = 1 + (rand()%11);
                    int dealerHit2 = x.userShowCardFour;
                    x.userTotal += dealerHit2;
                    x.cardCount++;

                }
                else {
                    if (x.userShowCardFive ==0) {
                        x.userShowCardFive = 1 + (rand()%11);
                        int dealerHit3 = x.userShowCardFive;
                        x.userTotal += dealerHit3;
                        x.cardCount++;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    if (x.hit == 2) {
        x.runGame = 2;
    }

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, you are asking why random numbers generated in one part of the program are not the same as random numbers generated in another part?

Comment: well i don't want the random number to be generated in the second part, i guess i want to convert the random numbers from the one part of the program into a static variable that i can then use later.

Comment: It is hard to figure out what exactly you are asking, but I doubt you want a static variable.  You are already storing the results in a variable, if you want to access it, just access it.

Comment: ok so i store the random numbers into the userTotal variable.  then, when i try to access it later to print out what the userTotal was, the userTotal is completely different than what it should be, which is userShowCardOne + userShowCardTwo etc..

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have 2 instances of the Game object and both are named x

```
int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    Game x;
    ...
    cout << "You had a total of: " << x.userTotal << endl;
```

then in the startGame function

```
int startGame() {
    Game x;
    ...
    if(x.hit == 1) {

        if (x.userShowCardThree == 0) {
            x.userShowCardThree = 1 + (rand()%11);
            int dealerHit1 = x.userShowCardThree;
            x.userTotal += dealerHit1;
            x.cardCount++;
```

The x in main() is not the same as x in startGame() as both are separate Game objects.